# Cutting hole in DIV with background image

Tags: html, css, svg

How would you cut multiple "holes" into a DIV that uses a background image? The DIV will be **dynamic in width**, but the holes will always be 20px away from each side, and halfway down vertically.

So to clarify, the div width will change, but I want to find a way to make two holes (one on the left and another on the right) that cuts through the DIV, that would reveal anything behind the DIV.

I've seen similar solutions that rely on SVG, but specifically place the circles to, rather than dynamically change position.

**Image Example** 
[image]

**Code Examples**

Codepen link: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rKNgXX

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #222;
}

p {
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
}

#example {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background: url("https://loremflickr.com/320/240");
  clip-path: circle(10px at 20px 50%);
}

#exampleTwo {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(20px 50%, circle, transparent 10px, #000 10px);
}
```

```html
<p>Using Clip Path (needs to be inverse, and have a second circle)</p>
<div id="example"></div>
<p>Using Radial Gradient (can't use background image, and have a second circle)</p>
<div id="exampleTwo"></div>
```

I've tried and failed with multiple methods.

Comment: What fails? Are you able to draw the circles without the images? Are the images rendered in front of the 'holes'?

Comment: In my first example, the area where the hole should be is the only thing being shown. Meaning I'd like to have it inverse. With the second method, I don't know how to get this to work with a background image. For both, I'm not sure how to add multiple holes.

Comment: so you have multiple images lying on top of each other (stacked), you want a hole placed on top image so that the image below that one appears through hole. is that what you want?

Comment: are you used `:after`, `:before` ?

Comment: The image example is just to demonstrate that the width of the div can change. What I want is two holes in the div, on each side of it.